# Proof that the estimation error in the LMS filter is uncorrelated

Tags: estimation, adaptive-filters, lms, wiener-filter

I need to demonstrate that the estimation error in the LMS adaptive filter is white.
The LMS equations are the following:

$y(n)={\mathbf{\hat{w}}}(n)^H\mathbf{u}(n)$

$e(n)=d(n)-y(n)$

${\mathbf{\hat{w}}}(n+1)={\mathbf{\hat{w}}}(n)+\mu \mathbf{u}(n)e(n)^*$

Where $\mathbf{u}(n)$ is the regressor, ${\mathbf{\hat{w}}}(n)$ are the coefficients, $d(n)$ the desired signal and $e(n)$ is the estimation error

From the (6.85) of [1] the estimation error can be expressed as:
\begin{equation}
e(n)\approx e_0(n)+\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_0^H(n)u(n)
\end{equation}

where $e_o(n)$ is the estimation error produced by the Wiener filter and $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_0(n)=\mathbf{w}_0-\mathbf{\hat{w}}(n)$ is the zero-order weight-error vector of the LMS.

Therefore, my aim is to compute $\mathbb{E}\{e(n)e(n-k)^* \}$. Following Haykin under the assumptions of $\mu$ small and $d(n),\mathbf{u}(n)$, jointly Gaussian I found that

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\{e(n)e(n-k)^* \}=\mathbb{E}\{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}(n)_0^H \mathbf{u}(n)\mathbf{u}(n-k)^H \boldsymbol{\epsilon}_0(n-k)\}
\end{equation}

However I was not able to prove that $\mathbb{E}\{\boldsymbol{\epsilon}(n)_0^H \mathbf{u}(n)\mathbf{u}(n-k)^H \boldsymbol{\epsilon}_0(n-k)\}=0$

[1] Simon Haykin, Adaptive Filter Theory, Fifth edition, Pearson 2014

Can anyone give me a helpful suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4790068/proof-that-estimation-error-in-lms-filter-is-uncorrelated). Try not to cross-post!